# Android Webview Not Playing HTML5 Videos

Tags: java, android, html, video, webview

While HTML5 video works on my Google phones, it no longer works on Samsung devices since I upgraded to api level 26 for my webview project. Whenever I visit YouTube on my webview app, the spinner spins endlessly and says "if playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device". Html5 videos on other websites work, however.

I've tried modfying the WebChromeClient for my WebView, but that did not do anything. Dom storage  is enabled as well.